# Change color of an element in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to make a nice Login Screen. My Problem is that I want to change the color of the Login text when I hover over the Username input.

For Example. There is a h1 Text with the content "Login".
When I hover over the Input under the Text i want the text change color

Comment: There is no parent selector in CSS. Also this question is too broad as there is no relevant code snippet of what you have already tried

Comment: this can be accomplished in javascript

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't select another parent's element with CSS. The only thing you could do is style the existing element, a child element, or a sibling element on hover.

For example, if the H1 text comes immediately after the input that you're hovering over, you could do this:

```css
input:hover + h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

OR, if you put both elements in a div and change the hovering effect to be triggered when the div is hovered, you could simply do:

```css
div:hover h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Ok I will try this too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to do this on mouse over event.

```
<h1 id="login">Login</h1>
<p>Username: <input type="text" onmouseover="changeLoginColor()"></p>

<script>
let login = document.getElementById("login");
function changeLoginColor(){
    login.style.color = "red";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly possible with CSS. You can't alter the style of an element that precedes the current one since it's cascading. You can, however, target a sibling which you can style to display before the input.

```
<div class="input-container">
  <input type="text" id="name" />
  <label for="name">Name</label>
</div>
```

```
.input-container {
  position: relative;
}
.input-container input {
  margin-top: 16px;
}
.input-container label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 4px;
}
.input-container input:hover + label {
  color: red;
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xeu4aszL/

Comment: That looks complicated but is understandable thank you

Comment: No problem. Feel free to ask if there's anything you might find confusing in the answer :)